# python string changed when using enumerate over path names

Tags: python, regex

I do face following odd behavior:

```
paths =['./01_data\\2017-04-12 yy\\data.xlsx', './01_data\\2017-05-01 dd\\data.xlsx', './01_data\\2016-11-18 xx\\data.xlsx', './01_data\\2017-10-11 dd\\data.xlsx']
```

the paths to my data file are generated by:

```
paths = [item for item in glob.glob('./01_data/**/**') if '.xlsx' in item]
```

I do loop over the file paths and want to extract the date from it:

```
# date measured
re_date = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
```

What does work:

```
dates = []
for i in len(paths):
    match = re_date.search(paths[i])
    if match:
        dates.append(match.group())
```

If I use enumerate, the paths are changed and \\ is converted to :

```
for item, file in enumerate(paths):
    print(file)

./01_data\2017-04-12 yy\data.xlsx
./01_data\2017-05-01 dd\data.xlsx
./01_data\2016-11-18 xx\data.xlsx
./01_data\2017-10-11 dd\data.xlsx
```

Same behavior with:

```
for file in paths:
    print(file)

./01_data\2017-04-12 yy\data.xlsx
./01_data\2017-05-01 dd\data.xlsx
./01_data\2016-11-18 xx\data.xlsx
./01_data\2017-10-11 dd\data.xlsx
```

Regex does not work with these strings because the missing '\\'. Any ideas why iteration over the list changes '\\' to '\' ? It is not a big deal to change my code but it took me quite a while to find the source of the error.

Comment: why do you vote for closing this question ? It is a legit question about the enumerate function in python and why it changes the strings.

Comment: You haven't shown the code where the regex isn't matching.

Comment: You are right, I should have checked that. The error was made somewhere else. I voted to close. 1 left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your strings aren't changing.  If you loop over paths without enumerate, and print the strings, you will see the same thing.  This is the difference between printing the str() of the string (single backslash, no enclosing quotes), and the repr() of the string (double backslash, with enclosing quotes).

```
>>> s = './01_data\\2017-04-12 yy\\data.xlsx'
>>> print(repr(s))
'./01_data\\2017-04-12 yy\\data.xlsx'
>>> print(str(s))
./01_data\2017-04-12 yy\data.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the `enumerate()` function. You're printing a string with double backslash. Double backslash when printing is understood like escaping a backslash, and that's why you get this result.
Try without the enumerate, it will give you the same result.

```
for file in paths:
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected...

```
dates = []
for item, file in enumerate(paths):
    match = re_date.search(file)
    if match:
        dates.append(match.group())
print(dates)
```

Prints:

```
['2017-04-12', '2017-05-01', '2016-11-18', '2017-10-11']
```

Read more about escaping characters and raw strings:

```
>>> print("\\")
\
>>> print(r"\\")
\\
```